# Switch Statment Give Always The default

Tags: php, html

I have a problem in my script in wampserver. It runs well. But in my hosting it doesn't display
the page which is named classed.php?cat=[category_Name_Example]

```
    <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
?>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

<?php
include 'includis/html_codes.php';
include 'includis/config.php';
$catID= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);

switch ($catID)
{


  case 'javascript' :
  $catName = "javascript";
  $PageTitle = "Javascript  ";
  $img = "img/javascript.png";
  break;

  case 'htmlandcss' :
  $catName = "htmlandcss";
  $PageTitle = "html ";
  $img = "img/html2.png";
  break;

  default:header('location: /404');
}
if (!isset($catID)){
header ('Location 404.php');
}
if (empty($catID)){header ('Location 404.php');}

 include 'includis/db.php';

?>
```

please help thanx :)

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`? Also *"it doesn't run"* is **not** a valid problem description.

Comment: Another thing; you should **always** `exit` after sending a *Location* header

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($catID)` just before the switch?

Comment: it's run i forget to include database connection in the top first

Comment: Phil i'm using it to prevent sql injection :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable reason is that you do not have an open database connection while calling to this function. In this case mysql_real_escape_string just returns false.

Comment: Thank you really  i didn't include the database connection in the top of the file i included now and it have run well thank you :)